# CL based method for adding HTTP Servers on IBMi system

Tags: apache, websphere, ibm-midrange

I have a need to develop a CL script to quickly deploy a web application across a set of IBMi systems.

Right now, I have everything set up where I can create the directories, deploy the configurations (with the correct modifications) and place the files all from the CL script, but I cannot get it to automatically create and start the HTTP Server.

All of the documentation I can find requires that the servers be set up through the "IBM Web Administration for iSeries interface." Which is pretty much useless if I am trying to automate the entire system.

The only CL commands I can find which are of use are STRTCPSVR and ENDTCPSVR . However, there does not seem to be a clear way to add the server to the underlying system to start it.

Does anyone know of a CL command that does this? If not, is there an object/member I can edit which would add a server to the HTTPA, set it to point to the already set up htdocs and conf directories and then I can start it with STRTCPSVR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Create Apache Server Instance (QzuiCreateInstance) API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaie/rzaieapi_qzuicreateinstance.htm) for a method to automate the creation of http instances.

> The QzuiCreateInstance() API allows users to create a new IBM® HTTP Server for i server instance.

Also the `QUSRSYS/QATMHINSTC` file contains a member for every configured instance.  Each member has one record that contains an entry in the format of `-apache -d /www/instancename -f conf/httpd.conf`.  You may be able to create members and add the record without using the API.

Comment: "QUSRSYS/QATMHINSTC" gave me just what I needed. I built an RPG program to create new members for that and I pop them in as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to:

- [How to Manually Create a HTTP Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1013611)
- [About_HTTP_directives_for_CGIDEV2](http://www.easy400.net/cgidev/pdfs/About_HTTP_directives_for_CGIDEV2.pdf)
- http://compgroups.net/comp.sys.ibm.as400.misc/create-an-apache-instance/1345746

**Quick Summary:**

1. Each HTTP server instance requires its own member in QUSRSYS/QATMHINSTC

   /QSYS.LIB/QUSRSYS.LIB/QATMHINSTC.FILE/`<SERVERNAME>`.MBR
2. The member above should contain one record

   -apache -d /www/`<SERVERNAME>` -f conf/httpd.conf -AutoStartN
3. Refer to /www in the IFS for for the file structure of the HTTP Server

   Use `<IBMi>`:2001/HTTPAdmin/ to create a sample HTTP server, which can be used as the basis for future generated HTTP Servers.
4. Starting / Stopping the HTTP Server instance

   srtcpsvr *http httpsvr(`<SERVERNAME>`)