# Automate Deployment IWS Webservices on IBMi

Tags: web-services, soap, ibm-midrange, rpgle

How does one go about automating the creation of Webservices on the IBMi?

Using the GUI at http://my.ibmi:2001/HTTPAdmin is a painfully slow process, and prone to fat finger errors. Thus my quest for automation.

During my research, I was unable to find the CL commands to export my RPGLE *SRVPGM procedures as Web Services.

Automation for IBMi V6R1 or V7R1.

Reference Sites:

- http://www.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/iws/‎
- http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/integrated_web_application_server_information.pdf
- http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_iws_pdf_WebServicesClient_new.pdf
- [CL based method for adding HTTP Servers on IBMi system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039145/cl-based-method-for-adding-http-servers-on-ibmi-system)
- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer found at**

- http://www.volubis.fr/news/liens/courshtm/AS400web/V6R1_LWI.htm

**All scripts relating to Webservices are in**

- /QIBM/ProdData/OS/WebServices/V1/server/bin

**Step:**

1. STRQSH
2. cd /QIBM/ProdData/OS/WebServices/V1/server/bin
3. installWebService.sh -h

> Command usage:
>    installWebService.sh
>       -server 'server-name' -programObject 'program-object'
>       [-service 'service-name'] [-pcml 'pcml-file'] [-userid 'userid']
>       [-libraryList 'library-list'] [-libraryListPosition  '*FIRST|*LAST']
>       [-disableNillableWSDLElements] [-disableOptionalWSDLElements]
>       [-addUnderscoreToWSDLElementNames] [-libraryListPosition  '*FIRST|*LAST']
>       [-printErrorDetails] [-help]
>
> Where:
>
> - **server** is the name of the Web services server in which the service
>     will be installed.
> - programObject is the integrated file system path to the ILE program or
>     service program. For example, '/QSYS.LIB/MYLIB.LIB/MYPGM.[SRVPGM or PGM]'
> - **service** is the name of Web service to be installed. This parameter is
>     optional. If not specified, the program object name will be used.
> - **pcml** is a path to the PCML file.  This parameter is optional. If not
>     specified, the program object must contain the PCML data.
> - **userid** is the user profile the Web service will be modified to run under. 
>     This parameter is optional. If not specified, the Web service will run
>     under the Web services server user profile. Note: The Web service server's
>     user profile needs to have *USE authority to the user profile specified on
>     this parameter. A value of *SERVER will ensure the Web service runs under the
>     same user profile as the Web services server.
> - **libraryList** is a list of libraries, that will be added to the library
>     list prior to invoking the Web service. Each library in the list must
>     be delimited by a colon. This parameter is optional.
> - **libraryListPosition** is the position in the user portion of the job
>     library list where the list of libraries specified in -libraryList will be
>     placed. A value of *FIRST inserts the libraries at the beginning of
>     the user portion of the library list.  A value of *LAST inserts the libraries
>     at the end of the user portion of the library list. This parameter is
>     optional. If not specified the default value of *LAST is used.
> - **disableNillableWSDLElements** will define elements in generated WSDL as
>     not nillable. If not specified, elements are defined as nillable.
>     This parameter is ignored for version 1.3 of Web services engine.
> - **disableOptionalWSDLElements** will define elements in generated WSDL as
>     not optional. If not specified, elements are defined as optional.
>     This parameter is ignored for version 1.3 of Web services engine.
> - **addUnderscoreToWSDLElementNames** will generate WSDL element names
>     that start with the underscore (_) character, as was always done in
>     version 1.3 of the Web services engine. If not specified, element names
>     in WSDL will not start with the underscore character.
>     This parameter is ignored for version 1.3 of Web services engine.
> - **printErrorDetails** will show additional error information, such as stack
>     traces and error codes, if the command fails. This parameter is optional.
> - **help** displays the command syntax. This parameter is optional.

Comment: The paths beginning '/QIBM/ProdData/OS/...' need to be edited. They're twice as long as needed due to an apparent duplication.

Comment: @user2338816 Please do the edit, and I'll review the change. Thanks.